# Creating extendable modules in custom cms

Tags: php, oop

I'm creating a custom cms for fun and it is based around different modules that are used for specific tasks. Each module is its own class and I have a bootstrap file that loads the modules required for the current site so that if, for instance, the Picture Gallery module isn't required it won't be loaded.

If I want to modify one of the modules (let's say I need a small modification in the news management module) I could copy the entire class to a local folder and do the modifications there. The bootstrap process picks up the local files if they exist over the core ones. This works fine but it seems like a terrible way of doing things. If I have a couple of lines to change only I still have to copy the whole file.

What would be the best way to handle customizable modules beside using local copies for files? I'm thinking I could create a new module say CustomNews extends CoreNews but I'm not sure how this would all tie in together. How would I go about loading the custom classes?

I'm mostly looking for general information about the process. Thanks!

Comment: How does the 'loading' happen? Does it just load the right files, or does it create the classes as well? If you have dependency injection, you are in control over the type of class that is created, and you can pass the instance to the CMS. There are many variations on this idea, but it's hard to give a concrete example, without knowing anything about your CMS.

Comment: Make your classes extendable, and your CMS configurable which class to use for which functionality (require a specific Interface rather then an Implementation), read up on dependancy injection, etc. If after those changes you still feel you need a custom class for something based of a available VCS repo of your choosing, branch it of to it's custom branch & use that one for the project, but it would mean manually merging new feature / bugfixes from the 'base' repo to your 'custom' project.